# Start workflow when field status changes

Tags: 2010, designer-workflow

Start a workflow when status field change to UOM Approval. I am using Sharepoint 2010

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't trigger a workflow based on a change to a particular field. Instead, set the workflow to run when an item is added to the list, and use the action titled "wait for field change in current item".

Comment: Thanks so much. So on start options. Do I check start automatically when the item is changed? or just keep the allow this workflow to be manually started checked. I really appreciate your help

Comment: I assume you want this to happen automatically for any item in the list? If so, start the workflow when a new item is added. Starting manually requires the user to both know how and to remember. Starting for each change means that this could happen multiple times.

Comment: Ok so one more question. I want it to go to a group but Im not seeing the option of who it should go to.

Comment: Want what to go to which group? (You should probably post this as a new question).

Comment: I want to create a workflow that assigned task to a group. I only want the workflow to start with the request status has been changed to UOM